# How to calculate conditional expectation of two independent poison r.v. ($E(N_1|N_1+N_2)$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Problem:

$N_1, N_2$ are 2 independent Poisson random variables, where $N_i \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda_i)$.
Please calculate $E(N_1\mid N_1+N_2)$ and $E(N_1+N_2\mid N_1)$.

---

I stuck at $$E(N_1\mid N_1+N_2) = \sum_{i=0}^niP(N_1=i\mid N_1+N_2=n)=\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom{n}{i}\frac{\lambda_1^n\lambda_2^{n-i}}{{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}^n},$$ since I cannot simplify this formula.

---

Please help me (A totally different method is also fine.), thx.

Comment: You have a typo: it should be $\lambda_1^i$ instead of $\lambda_1^n$.

Comment: Moreover $E(N_1|N_1+N_2)=\sum_{i=0}^niP(N_1=i|N_1+N_2=n)$ is not correct. It holds $E(N_1|N_1+N_2=n)=\sum_{i=0}^niP(N_1=i|N_1+N_2=n)$.

Comment: @mag: Yes, I also have those typos on my homework sheet, thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be derived that $N_1|N_1 + N_2$ ~ $Bin(n,\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 })$ where $T = N_1 + N_2$ and $n$ is the observed value of $T$. i.e. $$P(N_1 = i|N_1 +N_2 = n) = \binom{n}{i}\frac{\lambda_1^i}{{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)}^i}*\frac{\lambda_2^{n-i}}{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)^{n-i}}$$

Therefore $$ E(N_1|N_1 +N_2) = n \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2} $$

Since $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent, $$E(N_1 + N_2|N_1) = E(N_1|N_1) + E(N_2|N_1)$$ $$\implies E(N_1 + N_2|N_1) = N_1 + E(N_2) = N_1 + \lambda_2$$

Comment: Since $E(N_1\mid N_1 +N_2=n) =n\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$, the answer should be $
E(N_1\mid N_1 +N_2) = (N_1+N_2)\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$.

Comment: Yes, it is given that $N_1 + N_2 = n$

Comment: The point is that $E(N_1\mid N_1 +N_2)$ is a random variable. Your answer should reflect that.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I agree with you - $E(N_1|N_1+N_2)$ is a function whose parameter is $N_1+N_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} i\binom n i t^{i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac {n!} {(i-1)!(n-i)!} t^{i}=nt \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom {n-1}j t^{j}=nt(1+t)^{n-1}$. Take $t=\frac  {\lambda_1} {\lambda_2}$.

$E(N_1+N_2|N_1)=E(N_1|N_1)+E(N_2|N_1)=N_1+EN_2=N_1+\lambda_2$.

Comment: With regard to the typo one should take $t=\lambda_1/\lambda_2$.

Comment: @mag Thanks. I have corrected.